# SQL query add a column that is a SUM of rows after case

Tags: t-sql

If the below code offends anyone as a professional, let me apologize beforehand, now to the question:
After the below bit is done, it spits out exactly what i'm looking for, if the column has a string I get a 1 if not a zero.  My intent is to add a 7th column that adds these up so that I can funnel it into an equation in the report and compare it to another column.  I am sure that it is possible to do in the query, I just don't know how.
Server is sql 2008

```
    select CASE
WHEN [1  First Name] = ''
THEN 1
ELSE 0
    END as "First Name 1",
    CASE
WHEN [1  Last Name] = ''
THEN 1
ELSE 0
    END as "Last Name 1",
    CASE
WHEN [2  First Name] = ''
THEN 1
ELSE 0
    END as "First name 2",
    CASE
WHEN [2  Last Name] = ''
THEN 1
ELSE 0
    END as "Last Name 2",
    CASE
WHEN [3  First Name] = ''
THEN 1
ELSE 0
    END as "First Name 3",
    CASE
WHEN [3  Last Name] = ''
THEN 1
ELSE 0
    END as "Last Name 3"
    FROM
    member
```

Comment: You want a SUM per column? Or just count empty strings for all columns+rows in the table?

Comment: basically I want to count a row, so the total in the 7th column would be a number between 0 and 6 depending on how many columns have strings.  I am trying to explain this as best I can, i'm quite terrible at it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will SUM your 1s for all rows and columns

```
SELECT
    X.*,
    "First Name 1"+
        "Last Name 1"+
        "First name 2"+
        "Last Name 2"+
        "First Name 3"+
        "Last Name 3" AS TheSum
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        CASE WHEN [1  First Name] = '' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as "First Name 1",
        CASE WHEN [1  Last Name] = '' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as  "Last Name 1",
        CASE WHEN [2  First Name] = '' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as "First name 2",
        CASE WHEN [2  Last Name] = '' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as  "Last Name 2",
        CASE WHEN [3  First Name] = '' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as "First Name 3",
        CASE WHEN [3  Last Name] = '' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as  "Last Name 3"
    FROM
        member
    ) X
```

Comment: this is giving me a total of like 166000 in the end, what i'm looking for is like: first name/last name/first name2/last name2/first name3/last name3/total -- 1/1/0/0/0/0/2

Comment: Sorry I didn't notice you had edited, gah wish I could do 2 best answers.  Thank you both for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Unless I am missing something you can just place your current query in a subquery and then add a column with the total:

```
select "First Name 1",
    "Last Name 1",
    "First name 2",
    "Last Name 2",
    "First Name 3",
    "Last Name 3",
    ("First Name 1" +"Last Name 1"+"First name 2"+"Last Name 2"+"First Name 3"+"Last Name 3") As total
from
(
    select CASE
            WHEN [1  First Name] = '' THEN 1 ELSE 0
        END as "First Name 1",
        CASE
            WHEN [1  Last Name] = '' THEN 1 ELSE 0
        END as "Last Name 1",
        CASE
            WHEN [2  First Name] = '' THEN 1 ELSE 0
        END as "First name 2",
        CASE
            WHEN [2  Last Name] = '' THEN 1 ELSE 0
        END as "Last Name 2",
        CASE
            WHEN [3  First Name] = '' THEN 1 ELSE 0
        END as "First Name 3",
        CASE
            WHEN [3  Last Name] = '' THEN 1 ELSE 0
        END as "Last Name 3"
    FROM member
) m
```

Comment: That got it, as an aside why the "m" at the end (apologies if this is an ultra noob question)

Comment: @Jason1891 That is an alias for the subquery. SQL Server requires an alias on derived tables and subqueries. BTW you should accept gbn's answer, he edited his post with the correct version just as I posted mine. :)